# unable to access mySQL on mac

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL and had downloaded it to my computer (mac os X 10.7 lion).  I also downloaded SQLpro.  I am trying to access a database I have on my computer and am having trouble.  I try and type in the database name to open it and get this error:

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'name'
```

I have tried logging in as root and I also get the same error except the username is 'root'@'localhost'

I tried deleting mysql from the /usr/local folder and reinstalling it and I am getting the same error.  Also, after deleting it, the program I run can not find the database.  So I assume the database I used to have is gone.

Comment: can you provide more information. How are you accessing this. Via cmd on terminal, php code, etc...
May I recommend xampp, this way you can connect to your Database via a graphical user interface
[download xammp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
[access phpmyadmin gui](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/)

Comment: I am connecting using mysql via terminal on a mac running mac os x 10.7 lion.  I also tried using SequalPro but get the same error.  I am using it with a java program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I access MySQL from my Linux server which in the grand scheme of things should be no different than doing it from OS X

From Command Line, I have OS X at home and I have setup my root access so I would SU to do this.  On my Linux server I use SUDO
mysql -u"user"(I would use the root user) -p

then from there run the show database command

mysql> show databases;

Then chose the database you want to use

mysql> use "databasename";

Then go from there.

Hope this helps.